Calculating $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ without calculating the marginal $f_{X}(x)$
This question was asked in our test but I am not able to solve it

Let $Y$ be Gamma random variable with parameters $n,\lambda$ (with $\lambda>0$ and $n$ a positive integer). That is, $Y$ has density
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\lambda^ny^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y},\quad y>0$$
Let the conditional mass function of $X$ conditioned on $Y=y$ (with $y>0$) be Poisson with mean $y$. Calculate $\mathbb E[Y|X]$.
(hint: you do not need to calculate $f_X(x)$ explicitly)

My approach:
I was trying to get the expectation without calculating $f_{X}$ but was not able to move forward. So I tried calculating $f_{X}$ and then see if I observe something. I am facing problem even in calculating $f_{X}$.
So this is what I did for calculating $f_{X}(x)$.
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X \mid Y}(X)f_{Y}(y) dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}y^{x}}{x!} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \lambda^{n} y^{n-1} e^{-\lambda y} dy \\
&= \frac{\lambda^{n}}{x! \, \Gamma(n)} \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{n+x-1}e^{-(\lambda + 1)y} dy \\\\
&= \frac{\lambda^{n}}{x! \, \Gamma(n)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda+1)^{n+x}}{(\lambda+1)^{n+x}} \frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{\Gamma(n+x)} y^{n+x-1}e^{-(\lambda + 1)y} dy \\\\
&= \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(\lambda + 1)^{n}(\lambda + 1)^{x}} \frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{x! \, \Gamma(n)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+x)} (\lambda+1)^{n+x} y^{n+x-1}e^{-(\lambda + 1)y} dy \\\\
&= \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(\lambda + 1)^{n}(\lambda + 1)^{x}} \frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{x! \, \Gamma(n)} \\\\
&= \frac{(n + x - 1)!}{x! \, (n-1)!} \left(\frac{1}{\lambda + 1}\right)^{x} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\lambda + 1}\right)^{n}
\end{align*}
I am not sure what I found is correct or not ?. Also how can I do this without calculating $f_{X}$ ?
Thanks

Possibly related.

If think what the hint is trying to say is: if you want to compute the conditional density $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ (which is a function of the variable $y$), you can always do it up to a constant, here if you apply Bayes formula, the denominator $f_X(x)$ is a constant, hence you can ignore it. At the end, the constant factor you neglected must be exactly the normalization factor that makes your function a probability density!

Concerning the hint: A probability density function can always be computed up to a multiplicative constant. For example, if $Z$ has density $f_Z$ with
$$f_Z(z)\propto e^{-\lambda z},\quad z>0$$
we know that the multiplicative factor is
$$C:=\left(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda z}\text{d}z\right)^{-1}=\lambda$$
and that $Z$ follows an exponential distribution (with parameter $\lambda$). Indeed, it is the only constant $C$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} Ce^{-\lambda z}\text{d}z=1$$

A way to solve to problem without computing $\boldsymbol{f_X(x)}$: Here, by Bayes formula, for $x\in\mathbb N$,
$$f_{Y|X=x}(y)=\frac{f_Y(y)}{f_X(x)}f_{X|Y=y}(x)\propto f_Y(y)f_{X|Y=y}(x)=\frac{\lambda^n y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\frac{e^{-y}y^x}{x!}\propto y^{n+x-1}e^{-(\lambda+1)y}$$
Maybe we can recognize the Gamma distribution$^{\dagger}$, with parameters
$$\lambda':=\lambda+1\text{ and }n':=n+x$$
We would need to know the mean of such a distribution: we know that, for any choice of $\lambda >0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f_Y(y)\text{d}y=1\text{ or equivalently }\int_{0}^{+\infty}y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}\text{d}y=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\lambda^n}$$
In particular, taking $n+1$ instead of $n$ yields
$$\mathbb E[Y]=\int_{0}^{+\infty} yf_Y(y)\text{d}y=\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^{+\infty}y^ne^{-\lambda y}\text{d}y=\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\lambda^{n+1}}=\frac{n}{\lambda}$$
We already proved that, conditionally to $\{X=x\}$, $Y\sim\Gamma(\lambda+1,n+x)$, hence
$$\mathbb E[Y|X=x]=\frac{n+x}{\lambda+1}\text{ and }\mathbb E[Y|X]=\frac{n+X}{\lambda+1}$$

$^\dagger:$ by the way, the normalization factor can only be $\displaystyle\frac{(\lambda+1)^{n+x}}{\Gamma(n+x)}$, which could help you compute $f_X(x)$ if you really wanted:
$$f_X(x)=\frac{f_{X|Y=y}(x)f_Y(y)}{f_{Y|X=x}(y)}=\frac{e^{-y}y^x}{x!}\cdot\frac{\lambda^n y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{(\lambda+1)^{n+x}y^{n+x-1}e^{-(\lambda+1)y}}$$
$$=\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}\right)^x\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}\right)^{n}\binom{n+x-1}{x}$$
hence $X\sim \mathrm{NB}\left(n,\displaystyle\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}\right)$ (negative binomial distribution).
